# Render resource when PUT

Tags: clojure, liberator

I am using [liberator](https://github.com/clojure-liberator/liberator/) to build a API using Clojure. Given the follow code:

```
(defresource single-customer [id]
  :allowed-methods [:get, :put]
  :exists? (fn [_]
             (let [e (get @cust/customers (keyword id))]
               (if-not (nil? e)
                 {::entry e})))
  :existed? (fn [_] (nil? (get @cust/customers (keyword id) ::sentinel)))
  :available-media-types ["application/json"]
  :can-put-to-missing? false
  :put! (fn [q] (cust/set-as-fraudulent id))
  :handle-ok ::entry)
```

Someone when can tell me if is possible, like the GET request, when I send a PUT request it be redirected to the resource ? `"/customer/1"` (for example) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [liberator decision graph](http://clojure-liberator.github.io/liberator/assets/img/decision-graph.svg), `:put!` can lead to either:

- `:handle-created` (if `:new?`)
- `:handle-no-content` (if not `:new?` and not `:respond-with-entity?`)
- `:handle-ok` (if not `:new`, but `:respond-with-entity?`)

Try implementing `:put!` so it stores the entity as `::entry`, and `:handle-created` similar to your current `:handle-ok`.

Comment: Thanks @xsc, I will check the decision graph next time :)